# Wicket validator doesn't raise error on null field value

Tags: java, wicket, validation

How do I get my validator to raise an error on a null value?  I can see through my logs that when I try to submit a null field it's calling the validator, but it never raises onError so I cannot handle this.  I want to display an error message in a feedback panel when someone tries to submit an empty field instead of having to do a check in onSubmit of my form.

```
@Override
protected void onValidate(IValidatable<String> validatable) {

    String value = validatable.getValue();

    if (value == null) {
        ValidationError error = new ValidationError();
        error.addMessageKey("messageKey");
        validatable.error(error);
    }

}

@Override
public void validateOnNullValue() {
     return true;
}
```

*Edit*

If the above is not easily possible, is there a way that I can easily register an error message with a feedback panel when `component.setRequired` is true and the form is submitted with an empty field?  I just don't want there to be no feedback to the user when they try to submit the form with an empty field, but I also don't want to have logic for this in the onSubmit handler.

*edit 2* SOme more context

Here are two of the fields I'm trying to validate:

```
final TextField<String> currentLpnField = new TextField<String>("currentLpn", Model.of(""));
currentLpnField.setOutputMarkupId(true);
currentLpnField.setRequired(true);
currentLpnField.add(new BarcodeLPNValidator());

final TextField<String> upcField = new TextField<String>( "upc", new Model<String>() ); 
upcField.setOutputMarkupId(true);
upcField.setRequired(true);
upcField.add(new BarcodeUPCValidator());
```

Here is what's in my properties file:

```
upc.null=UPC cannot be null
upc.Required=UPC is required

currentLpn.null=LPN cannot be null
currentLpn.Required=LPN is required
```

I get the *.Required message only after i've entered info in the field, validated it, then delete it and try validating again.  If I just load the form and submit it without ever entering any data, I get nothing.

Comment: Why dont you set the field `setRequired()` ?

Comment: How do I display an error message in the feedback panel?  It's my understanding that with setRequired = true, the validators won't even be executed if the field is empty.

Comment: setRequired prevents the form from being submitted if the field is empty, but it still does not display an error message until after some data is input and then deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to validate a field if it is not empty then set the field required:

```
component.setRequired(Boolean.TRUE);
```

Then if you want to provide feedback to the user you have to use a `FeedbackPanel`. Configure the feedbackPanel to be visible when there are any messages:

```
private FeedbackPanel feedbackPanel;
feedbackPanel  = new FeedbackPanel("feedbackPanel") {
    @Override
    protected void onConfigure() {
        super.onConfigure(); 
        setVisible(anyMessage());
    }
};
feedbackPanel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
```

Then if you submit your form using AJAX you have to add the feedbackPanel to the `AjaxRequestTarget` to that it will get re-rendere and if there are any (error)messages the feedbackPanel will display the messages:

```
AjaxButton btn = new AjaxButton("button") {
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        super.onSubmit(target, form); 
        target.add(feedbackPanel);
    }
};
```

Additionally to get a good error message set a label for your component:

```
component.setLabel(Model.of("Username"));
```

Then if your field will be empty the error message will be:

> The field 'Username' cannot be empty.

Comment: Also, you can add a properties file to your project with which you can override the 'null-value'error.

Add a file called 'MyPage.properties' (for a class called 'MyPage', obviously) and enter a key-value pair as:

myform.mycontainter.mycomponent.null="Must submit value for mycomponent!"

Comment: It's interesting because when I load the page, if I just submit the form without touching any of the fields, I don't get any errors.  If I enter an invalid value in the field, submit the form, I get my validator error message as expected.  If I then clear that field and resubmit the form, I get the error message that I'm expecting for the null field that is defined in my properties file.  Why is it I cannot get this message when I submit the form before entering data and then clearing the field?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to validate a field if it is not empty then set the field required:

```
component.setRequired(true);
```

Then add a label for you error message

```
component.setLabel(Model.of("Username"));
```

Then add a a FeedbackPanel

```
FeedbackPanel feedback = new FeedbackPanel("feedback");
feedback.setOutputMarkupId(true);
form.add(feedback);
```

To finish, you have to  @Override the onError method in your AjaxSubmitLink :

```
add(new AjaxSubmitLink("save", form) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        super.onSubmit(target, form);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        super.onError(target, form);
        target.add(feedback);
    }
});
```

Then if your field will be empty the error message will be:

> The field 'Username' cannot be empty.